# Export as Excel file not working for HTML table in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing an chrome extension for my university and there is a problem i am facing, the 'Export as Excel' does not show up after i add jquery code in manifest.json as well as in timetable.js (Look below for more info)

Here is my code :

> Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "VIT Academics Enhancement Suite",
  "version": "0.1",
  "author": "Rahul Kapoor",
  "description": "Extension to help you improve your experience on VIT Academics",
  "permissions": ["*://academics.vit.ac.in/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/parent_login.asp","*://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp","*://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/","*://academics.vit.ac.in/student/","*://27.251.102.132/parent/parent_login.asp","*://27.251.102.132/student/stud_login.asp","*://27.251.102.132/parent/","*://27.251.102.132/student/"],
      "js": ["captcha.js"]
    },
    {

        "matches": ["*://academics.vit.ac.in/student/timetable_ws.asp"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["timetable.js"],
        "js": ["jquery.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://academics.vit.ac.in/*/attn_report.asp*","*://academics.vit.ac.in/student/attn_report_details.asp","*://27.251.102.132/*/attn_report.asp*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["attendance.js"],
      "css": ["home.css"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

> Timetable.js

```
var textbox = document.getElementsByName('regular')[0];
console.log(textbox);
    var para = document.createElement("input");

    var t = document.createTextNode("Show Password");
    para.setAttribute("type", "button"); 
    para.setAttribute("id", "btnExport"); 
    para.setAttribute("value","Export Table data into Excel");
    textbox.parentElement.appendChild(para);

$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('table:nth-child(1)').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The table HTML code has no id or class so i am targeting it using nth-child but as soon i add jquery.js in manifest which as CDN library code then the button 'Export as Excel' disappears.

Am i doing it right or is it something else i need to do, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you specify multiple script dependencies in the manifest:

```
"js": ["timetable.js"],
"js": ["jquery.js"]
```

In JSON, the latter entry will simply overwrite the former, *so now you no longer reference timetable.js*

The value for the "js" key is already an array (as denoted by the [ ]), so you just add your dependencies to that array:

```
"js": ["timetable.js", "jquery.js"]
```

I'm not sure in what order the scripts are injected, you might need to switch them around.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but my excel sheet comes with html content with the tags as a whole and not properly do you know why?